# Why do the coins only save the first time a player joins the game?

Tags: lua, roblox

So I am making an obby in Roblox. I have a data store for saving the leaderboard value which are coins and checkpoints. The Data Store I have is in the ServerScriptService.

The problem is that when the player joins the game for the first time, and they for example complete the first 5 levels of the game and they get 2 coins. The next time they join the game they are still on level 5 and they still have 2 coins from the previous game. But if they now play the game(i.e. they login to the game the second time) and let's say they reach level 10 and have 4 coins, the process should go like that if the player now leaves the game, and when they rejoin, they should be on level 10 and should have 4 coins.

But what happens is that on they are not on level 10 and they don't have 4 coins, they are on still on level 5 and their coins are 2. Just as their progress was on their first play.

Why doesn't this data store update the values on the leader board the third time the player log's in the game? And so on?

Here's the script which holds the whole data store which is located in ServerScriptService:

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local myDataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("myDataStore")


game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", player)
leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"

local Checkpoint = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
Checkpoint.Name = "Checkpoint"
Checkpoint.Value = 1

local coins = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
coins.Name = "Coins"
coins.Value = 0

--Checkpoint Section
player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character)

    repeat wait() until player.character ~= nil
    local checkpoint = game.Workspace.Checkpoints:FindFirstChild(Checkpoint.Value)
    character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart").CFrame = CFrame.new(checkpoint.Position + 
Vector3.new(0, 2, 0))

end)

-- Data Store Section

local playerUserId = "Player_"..player.UserId
print(playerUserId)

-- Load Data

local data
local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
     data = myDataStore:GetAsync(playerUserId)

end)


if success then
    if data then
    coins.Value = data.Coins
    Checkpoint.Value = data.Checkpoint
    -- Set our data equal to the current Coins
    end
end

end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
local playerUserId = "Player_"..player.UserId

local data = {

Coins = player.leaderstats.Coins.Value;
Checkpoint = player.leaderstats.Checkpoint.Value;

}

local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
    myDataStore:SetAsync(playerUserId, data)
end)

    if success then
        print("Data successfully saved!")
    else
        print("There was an error saving the data!")
        warn(errormessage)  
    end

end)
```

Please do help as I really need the answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me as well, I think that you are testing the game in Roblox Studio. In Studio, it sometimes gives an error. Try publishing the game and then check it will work.